# Como separar os resultados de um SELECT no MYSQL em 2 foreach no PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, select, foreach

Tenho um site de receitas onde trago a lista de receitas de acordo com a consulta abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM receitas WHERE titulo LIKE '%batata%' ORDER BY ordem
```

Eu queria mostrar os 3 primeiros resultados em destaque (com uma classe de CSS diferente) e o restante abaixo.

Eu pensei em fazer 2 foreach, o primeiro com os 3 primeiros destaque e o outro foreach com o restante dos resultados.

Minha dúvida: Essa é a melhor forma? Se sim, como posso fazer para o 2º foreach descontar os que já apareceram no 1º para não repetir?

Gostaria que o resultado final fosse:

```
<h2>Destaques</h2>
<div>
  <div class="destaque">Destaque 1</div>
  <div class="destaque">Destaque 2</div>
  <div class="destaque">Destaque 3</div>
</div>
<h2>Outros</h2>
<div>
  <div class="comum">Outro 1</div>
  <div class="comum">Outro 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize apenas um foreach. Exemplo:

```
<h2>Destaques</h2>
<div>
<?
foreach($receitas as $idx => $r) {
    if($idx <= 2) {
        echo '<div class="destaque">...</div>';
    }elseif($idx == 3) {
        echo '</div><h2>Comuns</h2><div>';
            echo '<div class="normal">...</div>';
        }elseif($idx > 3) {
            echo '<div class="normal">...</div>';
        }
    }
echo '</div>';
```

Note que o **idx** utilizado na condição está como menor ou igual a 2 pois este começa em 0.

**0** = Receita 01

**1** = Receita 02

**2** = Receita 03

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: show, isso é como se juntasse o foreach com o for? um dúvida nisso, é que eu gostaria de colocar um <h2> entre os destaques e os comuns, editei minha pergunta de como preciso do resultado final.

Comment: consegui usando o que vc mandou e uma combinação de ifs, posso editar sua resposta e colocar como resolvi?

Comment: Olá. Foreach e For são laços de repetição eficientes, mas o foreach serve para percorrer arrays ou objetos. Fico feliz que tenha conseguido! Pode sim.